# How to use lighten or darken colors as background of a v-btn in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-btn

I have a button like this on vuetify:

```html
<v-btn color="blue" icon>
  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Now I try to do this:

```html
<v-btn class="blue lighten-4" icon>
  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

While I was expecting just a lightened colour.

How can I achieve my goal? Note that here vuejs 2 is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by writing this:

```html
<v-btn color="blue--text text--lighten-4" icon>
  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

This is because the icon is considered as text and not as background

**EDIT:**

As @Adam Muse pointed out, a better solution could be adding the class on the `<v-icon>` tag:

```html
<v-btn icon>
  <v-icon color="blue lighten-4">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the color to your v-icon

```
<v-icon color="blue lighten4">
```

I'd avoid in-line stying it with blue--text

you can also use class="blue--text" for text

Comment: Well, if my solution makes the underlying problem more clear, yours is more elegant and the one to choose!

Comment: Wait sorry, you forgot to add the `lighten-4` thing, that was actually my goal...

Comment: you can do color="blue lighten-4"

Comment: Yes, it was just for completeness